# How to get users email address in Openfire / asmack?

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, openfire, asmack

I am developing a chat app for Android and I want to make a Profile option where I can show the selected friends profile like JID, Name, Email at first. I can get the roosters  JID and Name but there is no getter for email... How can i query it ? This is how I got JID and Name:

```
Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();

        for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {

            // Log.d(TAG, "User: " + entry.getUser());

            String[] temp = entry.getUser().toString().split("\\@");
            String name = entry.getName().toString();
            String email = "az@azaz.lol"; // there is no getter at entry.getEmail ??

}
```

I am just guessing that this is not how get email from rosters...

Comment: Do you mean 'JID' rather than 'email'? Email addresses are not stored in the roster.

Comment: JID its entry.getUser() I really did mean email. But oh well then I will get around this. Thanks for the info.

Comment: The only place you might get a user's email address is their vcard, see XEP-0054: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0054.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User email addresses are not maintained in the roster. Rather, they are stored in the 'ofUser' table under the column, `email`. This information is stored at the time the openfire account is created and is not publicly accessible.